# Replacing named 'parameters' within a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, parameters, preg-replace, laravel

### SOLVED:

Thanks to @SJFrK, my issue has been solved. The following class allows me to do what I need. The question follows the class.

```php
class Redirects
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Placeholder Types
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | An array of placeholder types thatalow specific characters in a source
    | route or URL.
    |
    */

    private static $placeholders = array(
        ':all' => '.*',
        ':alpha' => '[a-z]+',
        ':alphanum' => '[a-z0-9]+',
        ':any' => '[a-z0-9\.\-_%=]+',
        ':num' => '[0-9]+',
        ':segment' => '[a-z0-9\-\_]+',
        ':segments' => '[a-z0-9\-\_\/]+',
    );

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Computed Replacements
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | An array that contains converted source placeholders.
    |
    */

    private static $computed_replacements = array();

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Computed Replacements
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Class-scoped string that contains a replacement route or URL from
    | site.redirects.
    |
    */

    private static $destination;

    /**
     * Check for a redirect. If it exists, then redirect to it's computed replacement.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public static function redirect()
    {
        // Only do this if redirects have been defined.
        if (Config::has('site.redirects') && count(Config::get('site.redirects') > 0))
        {
            $route = URI::current();

            // Get the available placeholders from static::$placeholders and
            // convert them into applicable options for the pattern.
            $available_placeholders = '';
            foreach (static::$placeholders as $placeholder => $expression)
                $available_placeholders .= ltrim("$placeholder|", ':');
            $available_placeholders = rtrim($available_placeholders, '|');

            // Define the pattern.
            $pattern = '/\((\w+):('.$available_placeholders.')\)/';

            // Get the redirects.
            $redirects = Config::get('site.redirects');

            // For each redirect, convert all the place holders and resulting
            // values, and check for a match. If one exists, then redirect to it.
            foreach ($redirects as $from => $to) {
                static::$computed_replacements = array();
                static::$destination = $to;
                $from = rtrim($from, '/');
                $to = rtrim($to, '/');

                // Convert the placeholders in $from (if any)
                $converted_placeholders = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($captures) {
                    static::$computed_replacements[] = $captures[1];
                    return '('.static::$placeholders[":{$captures[2]}"].')';
                }, $from);

                // Get the replacements
                $converted_replacements = preg_replace_callback("#^{$converted_placeholders}$#i", function($captures) {
                    $output = static::$destination;
                    for ($c = 1, $n = count($captures); $c < $n; ++$c)
                    {
                        $value = array_shift(static::$computed_replacements);
                        $output = str_replace("<$value>", $captures[$c], $output);
                    }
                    return $output;
                }, $route);

                // If the current route matches the converted expression, then redirect.
                if (preg_match("!^{$converted_placeholders}$!i", $route))
                    return Redirect::to($converted_replacements, 301)
                        ->with('moved-from', $route)
                        ->with('moved-from-rule', "'$from': '".static::$destination."'");
            }
        }
        else return;
    }
}
```

### INTRODUCTION

I'm in the process of writing a static website bundle in [Laravel](http://laravel.com) (FTW), and have come accross something I can't seem to get around.

The app contains a configuration file (`config/site.php`), which - among other things - contains an array of redirect lookups. The idea is to check for a match in each lookup URI, and then redirect to the replacement URI (with a 301 redirect, of course) - useful for those moving a static HTML site over to my bundle.

The format of the array is:

```php
'redirects' => array(
    '<source>' => '<destination>'
)
```

Within the `<source>`, the user can include the following:

1. Regular Expressions
2. Laravel-style placeholders: `(:any)`, `(:all)`, `(:num)`, or `(:alpha)` - I added that last one.

For example, the user could use the following redirect (note that I have chosen to use angular parenthises for the `<destination>` as it a little more aesthetic - it is converted back down to its regex equivalent [see the class below]):

```php
'(:all).html' => '<1>'
```

This would direct any page ending with `.html` to a route that does not contain it. Example: `http://example.com/about.html` would redirect to `http://example.com/about`.

### THE PROBLEM

I would like to be able to 'name' each parameter for easy-reading (and pleasant coding). What I'd like to do is name each placeholder in `<source>` (this is optional, of course), AND define a placeholder-type. For example:

```php
'(name:all).html' => '<name>'
```

Now, considering that the placeholders *could* be named, they could naturally be in any order within the `<destination>`, for example (note the order changes in the destination URI):

```php
'Products/(name:any)-(category:any)-(id:num).html' => 'products/<category>/<id>/<name>/overview'
```

Using the regular placeholder syntax, I *could* interpret this as:

```php
'Products/(:any)-(:any)-(:num).html' => 'products/<2>/<3>/<1>'
```

This is the fallback anyway - I'd need to find out how to replace the names with their corresponding capture groups using `preg_replace`. But it seems to not be possible using named parameters/captures:

#### NAMED PARAMETERS

An easy route would be by using named parameters in `preg_replace`, but (as I understand this) PHP does not support it.

Using this method would enable me to use the same kind of replacement tools to get the task done - so not having it available is a little disappointing.

Nonetheless, I am happy to revert to something a little more complex (which is a good thing, anyway). Thing is, I have no idea how - and a solution is just not coming to me. I have had a look at the [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) `RouteCompiler` class, but do not understand it fully. I feel that, considering the backbone of Laravel is built upon the Symfony component-set (much like Silex), there may be a better way to accomplish what I need.

Has anyone had the same kind of requirements, and perhaps found a solution? Any help here would be simply awesome! Thanks in advance.

### CURRENT CLASS

Here's the source to the class that handles the redirects. I simply call `Redirects::handle()` in my `routes.php` file.

```php
class Redirects
{
    private static $placeholders = array(
        ':any' => '[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_%=]+',
        ':num' => '[0-9]+',
        ':alpha' => '[a-z]+', //added
        ':all' => '.*',
    );

    private static $replacement_identifiers = array(
        '(\<([0-9]+)\>)' => '$$1',
    );

    /**
     * Create the applicable regex placeholders
     *
     * @param  string  &$from
     * @param  string  &$to
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function placeholders(string &$from, string &$to)
    {
        // Replace the <source> with a match expression
        foreach (static::$placeholders as $placeholder => $expression)
            $from = str_replace("({$placeholder})", "({$expression})", $from);

        // Replace the <destination> with a replacement expression
        foreach (static::$replacement_identifiers as $identifier => $expression)
            if (preg_match($identifier, $to))
                $to = preg_replace($identifier, $expression, $to);
    }

    /**
     * Return the response of any redirects, or void if none
     *
     * @return Response|void
     */
    public static function handle()
    {
        $route = URI::current();
        if (Config::has('site.redirects'))
        {
            $redirects = Config::get('site.redirects');
            foreach ($redirects as $from => $to) {
                $from = rtrim($from, '/');
                static::placeholders($from, $to);
                if (preg_match("!^{$from}$!i", $route))
                {
                    if (strpos($to, '$') !== false and strpos($from, '(') !== false)
                        $to = preg_replace("!^{$from}$!i", $to, $route);
                    return Redirect::to($to, 301)->with('Moved-From', $route);
                }
                else return;
            }
        }
        else return;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you really think it's a good idea having a variable and a function with the same name?

Comment: Are you referencing the `placeholders` function? If so, I can change it. Not that I think it matters much...

Comment: Maybe the function `preg_replace_callback` could be used here? http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: @SJFrK: It is possible, though I'm not quite sure how to use it. I see that it uses `$matches[n]` - how would I be able to use it to look for names? I know it's never great to look at it this way, but I'd like to find the simplest route possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a test-case case that does what you want, maybe you can incorporate this into your class?:

```
<?php
class Redirects {
private static $placeholders = array(
    ':any' => '[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_%=]+',
    ':num' => '[0-9]+',
    ':alpha' => '[a-z]+', //added
    ':all' => '.*',
);

private static $tmp;
private static $tmpValue;

public static function handle() {
    $case = array('Products/(name:any)-(category:any)-(id:num).html' => 'products/<category>/<id>/<name>/overview');
    $test = 'Products/productName-categoryName-123.html';       // products/categoryName/123/productName/overview

    $pattern = '/\(\s*?(\w*?)\s*?:\s*?(\w*?)\s*?\)/';

    foreach ($case as $k => $v) {
        self::$tmp = array();
        self::$tmpValue = $v;

        $step1 = preg_replace_callback($pattern, array(self, 'replace_step1'), $k);
        $step2 = preg_replace_callback('#' . $step1 . '#', array(self, 'replace_step2'), $test);

        print 'case: ' . $k . '<br>';
        print 'step1: ' . $step1 . '<br>';
        print 'step2: ' . $step2 . '<br>';
    }
}

private static function replace_step1($matches) {
    self::$tmp[] = $matches[1];

    return '(' . self::$placeholders[':' . $matches[2]] . ')';
}

private static function replace_step2($matches) {
    $str = self::$tmpValue;

    for ($i = 1, $n = count($matches); $i < $n; ++$i) {
        $value = array_shift(self::$tmp);

        $str = str_replace('<' . $value . '>', $matches[$i], $str);
    }

    return $str;
}
}

Redirects::handle();
```

It first replaces your named placeholders with the real PREG placeholders and stores them in an array `$tmp`. It then checks the test-string `$test` if it matches that pattern `$step1` and replaces them according to the `$tmp` array.

Comment: Thank you -- will definitely give this a try when I get back home later, and will let you know if it works, of course. :)

Comment: This does indeed work for the named placeholders - thank you! And considering that it does, I would rather stick to it (it seems that falling back to numeric replacements with my parentheses does not work -- easy to fix, but I'd rather leave it). So, the user will only be able to make use of named placeholders or regex fallbacks. Once I have incorporated this into my class properly, I will post it for others to learn. Thanks again!