# preg_replace_callback not returning the correct data

Tags: php, regex, arrays, routes, uri

This is in relation to a previous question I asked before: [Replacing named 'parameters' within a string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745720/replacing-named-parameters-within-a-string-in-php)

That little class used to work, but it seems to be misbehaving, now that I'm attempting to move it over to the new Bolt CMS as an extension.

The intention is to grab data from a YML file. The data looks like so:

```
redirects:
    contentToPage:
        from: "content/(slug:any)"
        to: "page/{slug}"
```

The extension loops through this data and compares it to the current Request URI, obtained from the applicable Symfony component. If there is a match, the user will be redirected accordingly. So, in this case, if a user tried to visit `content/test`, they would be redirected to `page/test`.

Something seems to be going wrong though, where the converted replacement isn't correct, or I get thrown an error. First, here's the block in question:

```php
$convertedReplacements = preg_replace_callback("/^{$convertedPlaceholders}$/", function ($captures) {
    $result = $this->destination;
    for ($c = 1, $n = count($captures); $c < $n; ++$c) {
        $value = array_shift($this->computedReplacements);
        $result = str_replace("\{$value\}", $captures[$c], $result);
    }
    return $result;
}, $requestUri);
```

`$convertedPlaceholders` contains the replaced parameters in the `from` value. So, `(slug:any)` would be replaced with `([a-z0-9\.\-\_\%\=]+)`. Now, that works, but the function throws this exception: `preg_replace_callback(): Unknown modifier '('`.

However, if I change the regex delimiters from `/` to `~` or `#`, I don't get the error. Instead, I get the value of the `to` property in the YML file. In this case, I get `page/{slug}` and not `page/test`.

I must be doing something stupid, and I have no idea what it is. For all I know, there's just something that I left out that I can't see.

Here's the entire extension:

```php
<?php
// Redirector Extension for Bolt
// Minimum version: 1.2

namespace Redirector;

use Silex\Application as Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request as Request;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser as Parser;
use Bolt\BaseExtension as BoltExtension;

class Extension extends BoltExtension
{
    protected $placeholders = array(
        ':all' => '.*',
        ':alpha' => '[a-z]+',
        ':alphanum' => '[a-z0-9]+',
        ':any' => '[a-z0-9\.\-\_\%\=]+',
        ':num' => '[0-9]+',
        ':segment' => '[a-z0-9\-\_]+',
        ':segments' => '[a-z0-9\-\_\/]+'
    );

    protected $computedReplacements;

    protected $destination;

    /**
     * Basic information about the extension. Shown in the Bolt Admin Environment.
     *
     * @return Array
     */

    function info() {
        $data = array(
            'name' => 'Redirector',
            'version' => '0.1',
            'author' => 'Foundry Code - Mike Anthony',
            'description' => 'An extension that allows you to perform any pre-app <code>301 Moved Permanently</code> redirects.',
            'type' => 'Pre-app Hook',
            'link' => 'http://code.foundrybusiness.co.za/extensions/bolt-redirector',
            'first_releasedate' => '2013-08-28',
            'latest_releasedate' => '2013-08-28',
            'required_bolt_version' => '1.2',
            'highest_bolt_version' => '1.2'
        );
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Initialise the extension's functions
     *
     * @return void
     */

    function initialize() {
        $this->options = $this->config['options'];
        $this->redirects = $this->config['redirects'];
        $this->handleRedirects();
    }

    /**
     * Check for a redirect. If it exists, then redirect to it's computed replacement.
     *
     * @return ? Response
     */
    function handleRedirects()
    {
        $redirector = $this;
        $this->app->before(function (Request $request) use ($redirector) {
            if (empty($redirector->redirects)) {
                return;
            }
            $requestUri = trim($request->getRequestUri(), '/');

            $availablePlaceholders = '';
            foreach ($this->placeholders as $placeholder => $expression) {
                $availablePlaceholders .= ltrim("$placeholder|", ':');
            }
            $availablePlaceholders = rtrim($availablePlaceholders, '|');
            //die($availablePlaceholders);

            $pattern = '/\{(\w+):('.$availablePlaceholders.')\}/';
            //die($pattern);

            foreach ($this->redirects as $redirectName => $redirectData) {
                $this->computedReplacements = array();
                $this->destination = $redirectData['to'];
                $from = rtrim($redirectData['from'], '/');
                $to = rtrim($redirectData['to'], '/');

                $convertedPlaceholders = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($captures) {
                    $this->computedReplacements[] = $captures[1];
                    return '(' . $this->placeholders[":{$captures[2]}"] . ')';
                }, $from);
                //die($convertedPlaceholders);

                $convertedReplacements = preg_replace_callback("/^{$convertedPlaceholders}$/", function ($captures) {
                    $result = $this->destination;
                    for ($c = 1, $n = count($captures); $c < $n; ++$c) {
                        $value = array_shift($this->computedReplacements);
                        $result = str_replace("\{$value\}", $captures[$c], $result);
                    }
                    return $result;
                }, $requestUri);
                die($convertedReplacements);

                if (preg_match("~^{$convertedPlaceholders}$~i", $requestUri)) {
                    return $this->app->redirect("/$convertedReplacements", 301);
                }
            }
        }, Application::EARLY_EVENT);
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to what I can do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, it seems to be working now. For some reason, everything hopped into place when I changed:

```
str_replace("\{$value\}", $captures[$c], $result);
```

to

```
str_replace('{' . $value . '}', $captures[$c], $result);
```

I see it has something to do with escaping, which is weird. In the first one, I used double quotes, and escaped the curly brackets so that it would render as `{slug}`. But, for some reason, that did not happen. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `/` as regex delimiter, you should escape all the `/` characters in the regex, or, better, use another delimiter as you did.

Comment: That's the thing, the `:any` rule does not allow forward slashes. And when I do switch delimiters, I don't get the correct replacement.

Comment: Oh sorry, I see - forgot it was matching the whole string. Nonetheless, there's still something wrong with it.